# Qt Maemo resources screwed up in Scratchbox 1 for the armel target

Tags: qt, maemo, scratchbox, qt-maemo

When I compile my Qt Maemo application in Scratchbox 1, all of the image resources appear completely messed up and corrupted, and the program runs extremely slow. This only happens for the armel target, and works fine in i386.

I also get these errors at the console:

```
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x1
```

I've had this problem before, and the only way to fix it was to clean install scratchbox. It's definitely not my code as it happens with any Qt program being compiled in scratchbox for armel.

Does anyone know what might have happened?

Answer (score 1):

The armel target is only intended to compile applications, so is not possible to run graphical applications in the armel target under the Maemo SDK. Use the x86 target if you want to test your code inside scratchbox.

Comment: Most of the time it actually works. It gets in a state where it's permanently broken.

I had a bug that would only happen on the device and in the ARMEL target on the machine, so testing it in the ARMEL target was much faster until it broke.

But I switched jobs so I don't ever have to use Scratchbox again, yay!